# Django objects.dates('date', 'month') query is off by one month

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm putting together a billing system in Django and I'm having a strange issue. In my views.py I make a query to pull out the unique months in which payments were made. I then iterate over this list of months to figure out how much was paid each month.

The query works, and the number it calculates is correct, but it is off by one month when I show it through the template. So when I do a query, I get the totals for June, but I end up displaying the month as May in the template. I know it's easy to make a quick hack to make this work, but I want to understand why this is happening.

Code below:

```
# views.py

def reports_index(request):
    payment_months = Payment.objects.dates('date', 'month')
    payments_by_month = []
    for p in payment_months:
         monthly_payment = Payment.objects.filter(date__year=p.year, date__month=p.month).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
         yearly_payment = monthly_payment * 12
         payments_by_month.append([p, monthly_payment, yearly_payment])

    return render_to_response('reports.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))


# reports.html

{% load humanize %}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="tableStatic resize">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Monthly Payments Recieved</th>
                <th>Yearly Payment Estimate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for p in payments_by_month %}
                <tr class="gradeC">
                    <td>{{ p.0|date:"M Y" }}</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;">${{ p.1|intcomma }}</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;">${{ p.2|intcomma }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Did you tried displaying p.0.month instead of p.0|date:"M Y" in the template? If so, what did you see 6 or 5?.

Comment: p.0.month gives me a 6, which is the correct month, since I'm looking for June. Why the disconnect between the view and the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crikey! With a little help, it looks like I found the answer to my own question.

@esauro suggested that I check {{ p.0.month }} instead of {{ p.0|date:"M Y" }}, so this is all inspired by him.

{{ p.0.month }} = 6

{{ p.0|date:"M Y" }} = May 2012

The reason for the discrepancy is that my settings.py uses time zone info and I'm in the US -- which puts me a few hours behind GMT and into the previous day. Hence the May 2012, when I was expecting June 2012. The default Django setting is this:

```
# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True
```

If you set:

```
USE_TZ = False
```

Then you get no timezone-aware datetimes. Asking a followup question, does this only happen with sqlite? I'm just running a development server and I didn't realize this could change between development and production.

This is something that I had not really appreciated until now. The DB has its own date and time structure. And the Django ORM has mappings, but it depends on your Django settings. Small changes in TZ settings can largely affect something you previously thought was set in stone.

Hope this helps.